Sobolev-type spaces and orthonormal systems
Let $\mathcal{O}$ be a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^d$ with smooth boundary. Suppose that $\{e_n\}$ is an orthonormal system in $\mathbb{L}^2(\mathcal{O})$ and let $(\lambda_n)$ be a sequence with $\lambda_n < \lambda_{n+1}\to \infty$ for $n\to \infty$. Consider the space $\tilde{H}^s(\mathcal{O}) := \{f\in \mathbb{L}^2(\mathcal{O}):\,\Vert f\Vert_{\tilde{H}^s(\mathcal{O}}:=\sum \lambda_n^s \langle f, e_n \rangle_{\mathbb{L}^2(\mathcal{O}}^2< \infty\}$. Are there any choices of $e_n$ or $\lambda_n$, such that (subsets of) $\tilde{H}^s$ are closed subsets of the usual Sobolev space $H_0^s(\mathcal{O})$? My first thought was to consider eigensystems of the Laplace operator with zero-boundary condition - but I was not sure about the (higher) trace conditions needed to be an element of $H_0^s(\mathcal{O})$. Another thought would be to multiply $e_n$ with some cut-off function $\xi$ - but are then $\xi e_n$ again forming an orthonormal system?
Thanks a lot!!
